# session.upload_progress.name not support multiple files upload with formdata

Tags: javascript, php, form-data

i'm trying to use pure javascript and php to upload some picutres (with progress bar) and it seems it works with only one file but doesn't support multiple files at the same time.
i use js formData and php session.upload_progress.name to do that.

here if the form where i select the files:

```
    <form style='display:none;' method='POST' action='/profile/picture/upload'  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='hidden' name='progress' value='".ini_get('session.upload_progress.name')."'/>
        <input type='file' name='files' multiple/>
    </form>
```

here is the js to upload the files

```
    var submitFiles = function(form) {
        var xhr;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        var formData = new FormData();
        xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute("action"), true);
        formData.append(form.progress.value, "123");
        for (var i = 0; i < form.files.files.length; i++)
            formData.append("mfile[]", form.files.files[i]);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){callBack(xhr)};
        setTimeout(function(){uploadProgress(form);}, 500);
        xhr.send(formData);
};
```

and here s the progress bar function (not finished)

```
    var uploadProgress = function(form){
    var xhr;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr=new XMLHttpRequest(); else if(window.ActiveXObject) xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); else return;
    xhr.open("POST", form.getAttribute("action"), true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4){
            if(xhr.status == 200){
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                timer = setTimeout(function(){uploadProgress();}, 500);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send();
};
```

and here is the php to return the progress status

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/php_common/php_header.php"); //to start session 
echo("SESSION:");print_r($_SESSION);
```

all of this work and  have feed back about the upoload progress when  select only one file:

```
    SESSION:Array
(
    [UID] => 1000000000
    [upload_progress_123] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 1439971492
            [content_length] => 3080300
            [bytes_processed] => 5239
            [done] => 
            [files] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [field_name] => mfile[]
                            [name] => 7027380-dream-land-nature.jpg
                            [tmp_name] => 
                            [error] => 0
                            [done] => 
                            [start_time] => 1439971492
                            [bytes_processed] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

but if i select many files it doesnt work:

```
SESSION:Array
(
    [UID] => 1000000000
)
```

can you plz tell me why this doesnt work and how i can upload files (with progress feedback) using pure js (no jquery or other framework) and php. thank you for all help.

Comment: hello is there someone who can help on this issue? why i can't get help on my question lately on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Well i was missing (or better said forgetting a point here) it's that the posted files are larger than what allowed by apache php default setting.. 
for those that may have same problem think about editing:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.8\bin\php.ini
```

and changing those values to your needs :

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

example taken from a web site you may not need all of that memory and times:
for me i set

```
post_max_size = 99M
upload_max_filesize = 99M
max_execution_time = 500
max_input_time = 500
memory_limit = 128M
```